# 配列の中にオブジェクト型が入っているインスタンス変数をWhere句で得られる結果と同じオブジェクト型に変換する方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Postクラスがあり、Where句を使って複数Postを検索するとそのオブジェクト型はPost型に入っています。

```
@posts.where(state: 'published')

pry> @posts
=> [#<Post id: 12, name: "1st post" state: "published", user_id: 4, created_at: "2015-06-05 08:03:09", updated_at: "2015-06-05 12:41:53">,
 #<Post id: 23, name: "14th post" state: "published", user_id: 3, created_at: "2015-06-15 18:30:08", updated_at: "2015-06-15 18:30:08">]

pry> @posts.class
=> Post::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

この状態だと、Postクラスに指定したメソッドが使えます。

ところが、あるインスタンス変数(@instance)でそれは配列の中にPost型が入っている状態で得られます。

```
pry> @instance
=> [#<Post id: 12, name: "1st post" state: "published", user_id: 4, created_at: "2015-06-05 08:03:09", updated_at: "2015-06-05 12:41:53">,
#<Post id: 23, name: "14th post" state: "published", user_id: 3, created_at: "2015-06-15 18:30:08", updated_at: "2015-06-15 18:30:08">]

pry> @instance.class
=> Array
```

この型だと当然ながらPostクラスに指定したメソッドが使えません。
    `NoMethodError - undefined method 'search' for #<Array:`
ではじかれます。
解決するには配列の型をPost型に変換するべきと思うのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本当はinstanceが配列になる前に、

```
@posts = Post.where(state: 'published')
@instance = @posts.to_a
```

というようにし、`@posts`を使って別のクエリは扱うようにするのがいいと思います。

ただ、そういうのが難しい、もしくはめんどくさい場合、

```
Post.where(id: @instance)
```

とすれば、解決できます。

結局idを元にDBを引き直しているだけですが。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
Post.where(id: @instance)とすれば@instanceの中に含まれるPostが全てヒットするとは、知りませんでした。助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

> Postクラスがあり、Where句を使って複数Postを検索するとそのオブジェクト型はPost型に入っています。

正確には`Post`クラスではなく`Post::ActiveRecord_Relation`クラスでこれは`ActiveRecord::Relation`のサブクラスです。

さて、一度配列になったものを`ActiveRecord::Relation`に戻す機能は無かったと思います。

ただ、勝手に配列に変換されることもないので、どこかの処理で配列にしてしまっているのだと思います。その処理を見直すことでしょうか。

または配列から`id`だけ引っ張り出して検索しなおすかです。

ところで、`search`メソッドは`ActiveRecord::Relation`にもないので、質問の例では`@posts.search`とやってもやはりundefined methodになるはずです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。
配列にしてしまっているのはGemのライブラリ内なので、抜本的な見直しを検討してみます。

Comment: > ところで、searchメソッドはActiveRecord::Relationにもないので---
まさにご指摘の通りで、searchメソッドは独自にPostクラスに設定したメソッドになります。この点も質問に記載しておくべきでした。